# Arbitrarily dockable windows / widgets in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qtwidgets, dockable-windows

Qt 5.2 or later, widget based GUI (no QML)

Dockable widgets in Qt are possible ([example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/mainwindows-dockwidgets.html)). However, usually one can dock a widget in a dockable area of a larger surrounding parent frame. I wonder whether there is a way to attach floating windows with each other, as it is possible in WinAmp (see screenshot).

Can someone point out whether something like this can be done with Qt?

[image: WinAmp docking]

Comment: [Kdenlive](http://kdenlive.org/) does this somehow -- you could look at how they do it.